# How to show what will be updated next pull?

Tags: git

In SVN, doing `svn update` will show a list of full paths with a status prefix:

```
$ svn update
M foo/bar
U another/bar
Revision 123
```

I need to get this update list to do some post-process work. After I have transferred the SVN repository to Git, I can't find a way to get the update list:

```
$ git pull
Updating 9607ca4..61584c3
Fast-forward
 .gitignore                                         |    1 +
 uni/.gitignore                                     |    1 +
 uni/package/cooldeb/.gitignore                     |    1 +
 uni/package/cooldeb/Makefile.am                    |    2 +-
 uni/package/cooldeb/VERSION.av                     |   10 +-
 uni/package/cooldeb/cideb                          |   10 +-
 uni/package/cooldeb/cooldeb.sh                     |    2 +-
 uni/package/cooldeb/newdeb                         |   53 +++-
 ...update-and-deb-redist => update-and-deb-redist} |    5 +-
 uni/utils/2tree/{list2tree => 2tree}               |   12 +-
 uni/utils/2tree/ChangeLog                          |    4 +-
 uni/utils/2tree/Makefile.am                        |    2 +-
```

I can translate the Git pull status list to SVN's format:

```
M .gitignore
M uni/.gitignore
M uni/package/cooldeb/.gitignore
M uni/package/cooldeb/Makefile.am
M uni/package/cooldeb/VERSION.av
M uni/package/cooldeb/cideb
M uni/package/cooldeb/cooldeb.sh
M uni/package/cooldeb/newdeb
M ...update-and-deb-redist => update-and-deb-redist}
M uni/utils/2tree/{list2tree => 2tree}
M uni/utils/2tree/ChangeLog
M uni/utils/2tree/Makefile.am
```

However, some entries having long path names are abbreviated, such as `uni/package/cooldeb/update-and-deb-redist` is abbreviated to `...update-and-deb-redist`.

I deem I can do with Git directly, maybe I can configure `git pull`'s output in special format.

Any idea?

**EDIT**

I've figured out a resolution to this:

First, save the last and current commit to variable `PREV` and `NEXT`:

```
$ PREV=`git show --format=format:%H --summary | head -1`
$ git pull
$ NEXT=`git show --format=format:%H --summary | head -1`
```

And then, compare the two commit using special format:

```
$ git diff --name-status $PREV $NEXT
```

This will give the output:

```
A       .gitignore
M       uni/.gitignore
A       uni/package/cooldeb/.gitignore
M       uni/package/cooldeb/Makefile.am
M       uni/package/cooldeb/VERSION.av
M       uni/package/cooldeb/cideb
M       uni/package/cooldeb/cooldeb.sh
...
```

Which is exactly the same as Subversion's.

Then, it's also easy to make it in preview mode:

```
$ PREV=`git show --format=format:%H --summary | head -1`
$ git stash
$ git pull
$ NEXT=`git show --format=format:%H --summary | head -1`
$ git diff --name-status $PREV $NEXT
$ git reset --hard $PREV
$ git stash pop
```

Comment: Are you tying to "show what will be updated next pull" (title of your question or convert `git pull` to SVN's format?

Comment: I'm trying to show what will be updated next pull. The exactly path names is just enough.

Comment: Unfortunately, `git pull -v` doesn't get the full pathnames.

Comment: It's strange, actually `git pull --no-commit` do commit anyway.

Comment: Yes, it's strange - I reflected your finding in my response.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the full paths here - I understand your title question a bit differently, but if you already ran `git pull` then you can see the full path like this `git log --stat --raw -n 1` - this will show the last commit files in raw format (to avoid opening `less` use `git --no-pager ...`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first option of `man git-pull` is:

```
   --no-commit

       With --no-commit perform the merge but pretend the merge failed and
       do not autocommit, to give the user a chance to inspect and further
       tweak the merge result before committing.
```

<strike>So use `git pull --no-commit`.</strike>

**EDIT:** Oops! This does not work. As 谢继雷 (question's author) pointed out `git pull --no-commit` will still commit.  I'm using `git version 1.7.0.4`.

If you don't what the changes that got pulled in, then there is a way to go back:

```
git branch bad-branch-1
git log                          # Find the point you want to restore to,
                                 # for example: 35da5f07ca2c5

git reset --hard 35da5f07ca2c5   # Rolls back history and files
```